# Vtiger Include Model Class from cron file

Tags: vtiger

i need to include vtiger model class for accessing methods and avoid code duplication. i have php file in root . how can i access function in "Vtiger" Model class.

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Utils.php'; 
require_once('include/database/PearDatabase.php'); 
require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'includes/Loader.php';
vimport ('includes.runtime.EntryPoint');
global $current_user;
$current_user = Users::getActiveAdminUser();
$obj = new Settings_Newmodel_SyndicateCredential_Model();
```